# Visio - IDEF1X Data Modeling - How to set Alternate Keys

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, visio

Can anyone help me in defining `Alternate Keys` in `Visio 2010` for `IDEF1X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still on Visio 2007, hopefully 2010 is no different...

1. Left-click on the entity, and at the bottom of the screen choose *Indexes*.
2. Use the *New* button to create a new index, then use the *Index type* combo box to designate it as "Unique with constraint on top":

   [image]
3. The alternate key will be denotes by "Ux" in the entity:

   [image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. That is close to what I was trying, except the type index combobox selection. Still, shouldn't alternate keys be shown in the non-primary key columns rectangle? Visio places them, on top like it is part of the primary key. By the way I'm using the IDEF1X symbol set on database display options, not relational. 

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v415/techblank/visio_zps819c529a.png

Comment: @Pantelis I don't think Visio 2007 supports IDEF1X, so I can't really comment. For what it's worth, I used IDEFX1 under ERwin in its day, and I don't remember it placing alternate key attributes to the PK rectangle (unless they are _also_ part of the PK). What happens if you switch to "relational" notation?

Comment: For some reason Visio added the two attributes in the Primary Key. Their PK checkbox under columns in the category listview was checked when the index was added. Just had to uncheck it. Thanks!